# Slug and rename the same field in Django Serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

If I have it correct (and this is the way I use it) SlugRelatedField in Django Serializer can be used to return the string value from the ID of a foreign-key field.
Like I said I regularly do this. I also regularly change the field name in a table to something different by using CharField.

But how do I use both of these together? What I have so far is:

```
class ProductContainersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    containernameid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False, slug_field='containername', queryset=Productcontainernames.objects.all())
    container = serializers.CharField(source='containernameid')
    productid = serializers.SlugRelatedField(read_only=False, slug_field='productid', queryset=Productlist.objects.all())


    class Meta:
        model = Productcontainers
        fields = ('productid, 'container')
```

The model has two fields:

```
class Productcontainers(models.Model):
    containernameid = models.ForeignKey(Productcontainernames, on_delete=models.CASCADE) 
    productid = models.ForeignKey(Productlist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The above would work fine, if it was not for the fact that when I run my code it says that I must include the `containernameid` due to the fact that I have declared it. This kind of defeats the purpose because now I basically send the same information through twice (as container and containernameid).

**How can I return the string value (not id) of `containernameid` AND change the name of the field to `container`?**

Current output: Error -> `The field 'containernameid' was declared on serializer ProductContainersSerializer, but has not been included in the 'fields' option.`

Expected (desired) output:

```
0:{productid: "Prod1", container: "Box"}
1:{productid: "Prod2", container: "Crate"}
2:{productid: "Prod3", container: "Crate"}
3:{productid: "Prod4", container: "Box"}  etc
```

Output without changing Serializer in any way:

```
0:{productid: 1, containernameid : 1}
1:{productid: 2, containernameid : 2}
2:{productid: 3, containernameid : 2}
3:{productid: 4, containernameid : 1}  etc
```

Comment: Can you add the *current output* and *expected output* to question ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: Done.

Comment: Can you add `Productcontainers` model ?

Comment: Why didn't you add 'containernameid' to 'fields' ?

Comment: @Madi7 Because as my question states (and you can see in the serializer), I want to change `containernameid` to `container`. `containernameid` should become `container` and show the `string` value, not the `id`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge: Ah sorry, that was actually the model I wanted to add and then added the wrong one. Fixed now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understood your question correctly, the [`StringRelatedField()`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield) would apt in your context

```
class ProductContainersSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    productid = serializers.StringRelatedField()
    container = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='containernameid')

    class Meta:
        model = Productcontainers
        fields = ('productid', 'container')
```

**NOTE**:
**`StringRelatedField`** may be used to represent the target of the relationship using its `__unicode__`  or `__str__` method.

Comment: Thanks JPG, you did understand me correctly and that was exactly what I was looking for. Somewhere I got into my head that `SlugRelatedField` was the way to get the string representation of the id, and from there on I was searching for the wrong information the whole time. Thanks for the great help!